# Class 'BookModel' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create Paginated Data Table.But I am getting  error  I have searched for similar theads on Stackoverflow  but couldnt find a solution.. My  programming knowladge is very limited.So I dont know how to fix it and where this error come from .Thanks for help

This is  Mydata Class that extends DataTableSource

```
class MyData extends DataTableSource {
  var controller = Get.find<Controller>();
  var _data;
  MyData() {
    _data = controller.books;
  }
  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text(_data[index]['name'].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(_data[index]['writer'].toString())),
      ],
    );
  }
```

This is BookModel class

```
class BookModel{
  String _name;
  String _writer;
  String _img;
  String _price;
  String _webSite;


  BookModel(this._name, this._writer, this._img, this._price, this._webSite);
```

This is CreateTable class

```
  var controller = Get.find<Controller>();
  final DataTableSource _data = MyData() ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bodyData();
  }

  Widget bodyData() => PaginatedDataTable(
    source: _data,

    columns: const [

      DataColumn(label: Text('WebSite')),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Book Name'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `_data[index].name` and why do you need `toString()` method?
I assume that name is already a string.

And in models class, underscores are not needed, as they are used to declare private variables.

Try with `_data[index].name`.

Answer (score 0):

- Your model `BookModel`'s attributes are private, this means that they are inaccessible from outside the `.dart` file that contains the class
- using `[index]['key']` works only if your data list is a `List<Map>` but your data list is List, so your code should be `DataCell(Text(_data[index]._name.)),`
  Note that it won't work if the `BookModel` class is in another dart file and your need to change the fields names to be publish **without the leading `_`**, and then your code should be `DataCell(Text(_data[index].name.))`